# How can I insert a document fectched through find in an another collection in mongodb python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I fetched a document in python like this:

```
the_document = movies.find({'hostname': database_check})
```

Now I want to insert it in another collection. I tried various methods like:

```
clean = str(json.loads(dumps(the_document)))
new_collection.insert_many(result)
```

It always gives me some sort of error. Is there a good way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: If you don't need the document on python, all you want is to move it to another collection, you can use `$merge` to do it in one simple query.

Comment: Isn't that a mongodb cli command? how do i do it in python? i need the_document line.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is very simple. I did it using:

```
for a in movies.find({'hostname': database_check}):
            
            new_collection.insert_one(a)
```